# В какой коллекции хранить упорядоченную последовательность?

Tags: java, коллекции

Здравствуйте!

Такой вопрос: какой тип коллекций подходит для хранения упорядоченной последовательности объектов, часто добавляемых и удаляемых в середине коллекции?

Вот из этих типов: `ArrayList, LinkedList, Vector, TreeMap`. Что наиболее подходит для таких целей?

Comment: LinkedList? Может TreeMap?

Comment: почитай эту [статью ][1]


  [1]: http://habrahabr.ru/post/162017/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если исходные данные не сортированы, то сортировать их в LinkedList будет слишком затратно. 
LinkedList будет не очень удобно использовать в случае, если не всегда новый элемент по порядку идёт в середину. В итоге всё просто сведётся к поиску места для вставки нового элемента. Связный список для этого не подходит.

В случае ArrayList нужно при каждой вставке правую часть элементов сдвигать.

Лучше всего для данной задачи может подойти TreeSet - структура на основе Красно-черного дерева. Поиск и вставка за O(ln(n)).

Answer (score 4):

LinkedList, за постоянное время может выполнять вставку/удаление элементов в списке. Доступ к произвольному элементу осуществляется за линейное время. То есть он более эффективен при частой вставке элементов в середину.

Если вы хотите упорядоченную структуру то это TreeSet.

Comment: На практике, однако, использование `ArrayList` оказывается практически всегда производительнее даже для вставки в середину за счёт низкой амортизированной стоимости выделения памяти.

Answer (score 2):

Может я ошибаюсь, но я бы ArrayList взял. Добавление по индексу, удаление по индексу или ссылке на объект - удобно, и шаманить с индексами особо не надо. Правда, насчёт упорядоченности не уверен - если только контролировать её в коде. TreeMap - если объекты будут сортироваться по ключу и именно заменяться: ключ тот же, а объект меняется. Хотя, может я не до конца вопрос понял.

Comment: если данных очень много, то добавление и удаление из средины необходимо шевелить пол массива данных   

  Я думаю в этом случае лучшим вариантом будет LinkedList

Comment: Лучший ответ уже отметили и это действительно правильный ответ - TreeSet. Листы не являются сортированными коллекциями. В этом главная проблема.Надо сначала добавить все элементы, а потом их отсортировать. При большой структуре это весьма нетривиальная задача...